# Converting List<Character> to char[] and then to String

Tags: java

I've tried the following:

```
List<Character> randomExpression = new ArrayList<Character>();
String infixString = new String(randomExpression.toArray());
```

But this won't work because there is no String conctructor with an `Object[]` parameter.

Comment: A List of Character is an extremely inefficient structure.  I suggest you re-write you code to use a StringBuilder which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: I need the List to call Collections.sort() on it

Comment: Is there a reason [Arrays#sort(char\[\])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(char[])) won't work?

Comment: No reason at all! Nice tip, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you've probably noted, `char[]` is something different than `Character[]`, and there's no immediate way of transforming one to another in the standard API.

In this particular situation, I'd probably go with something like:

```
String result = chars.stream()
                     .map(String::valueOf)
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Or, pre Java 9:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(chars.size());
for (char c : chars)
    sb.append(c);
String result = sb.toString();
```

---

An alternative is to use the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) method [`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/index.html):

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
// ...
Character[] charArr = chars.toArray(new Character[chars.size()]);
String str = new String(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(charArr));
```

Comment: "String result = chars.stream()"?  You can't AFAIK stream a native char[]

Comment: If you have a native `char[]` you can simply do `new String(chars)`. In this case OP started with a `List<Character>`.

Answer (score 2):

`String` will need array of primitive `char` anyway and you can't convert Character[] to char[] directly. So your best bet is to iterate through list and build `char[]` array to pass to `new String(char[])`.

In code it would be something like this:

```
    char[] tmp = new char[randomExpression.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        tmp[i]=randomExpression.get(i);            
    }
    String infixString = new String(tmp);
```