# Java Random Class that Outputs Letters (A to E)

Tags: java, random, letter

So I'm creating a program that output 3 random letters from A to E. The issue is that it should also include lowercase A to E( A,a,B,b,C,c,D,d,E,e)

This is what I used to print out a random letter.

```
letterValue = (char) (rand.nextInt(5) + 'A');
System.out.print(letterValue);
```

The variable 'letterValue' should print out A to E, both Uppercase and Lowercase.

Comment: `(char) (rand.nextInt(5) + rand.nextBoolean() ? 'A' : 'a');`

Comment: Do the letters have to be different? Would A, b, A be valid output? Would A, b, a?

Comment: That is not working @flakes.

Comment: @Majestic, in what way not working? If you tried it, how did the output differ from what you wanted? If you would like our help, I think you need to be specific.

Comment: Just set the necessary brackets and it works: `(char) (rand.nextInt(5) + (rand.nextBoolean() ? 'A' : 'a'));`.

Answer (score 1):

One very elegant way of doing this: simply use an array with the values you intend to "random" on; and then shuffle that array. And when you turn to Javas List class, you can use the built-in [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) method:

Like:

```
List<Character> values = Arrays.asList('A', 'a', ... );
Collections.shuffle(values);
```

If you insist on using an array of char instead of that `List<Character>` ... you can still use the above approach, as you can easily convert that List into such an array, too (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702035/converting-listcharacter-to-char-and-then-to-string) for example).

When not using an array, you can "flip another coin"; meaning: just get another random value, maybe 0 or 1. With 0; just keep the uppercase value; for 1, simple use the corresponding lowercase value.

(and you know you can get from 'A' to 'a' using "maths", too - similiar to what you are already doing here)

Comment: How do I do it without arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
        letterValue = (char) (rand.nextInt(5) + 'A');
        if (rand.nextBoolean()) {
            letterValue = Character.toLowerCase(letterValue);
        }
        System.out.print(letterValue);
```

This is just one way out of many. I’m using your own code and trying not to complicate the task more than necessary. I ran this three times since you wanted 3 random letters, and it printed `d`, `d` and `C`.